# flv does not play

Tags: flash

I have a FLV file intended to be played with JW Players, however it won't play. I have windows server 2008, in IIS under the website I have .flv in MIME Types.

Extension: .flv MIME Type: flv-application/octet-stream

But on the browser, FLV doesn't play, the player is displayed though so no problem with my flash player.

In my other server (windows server 2003), it plays.

Can someone help?

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the MIME type is set on all top level folders in your IIS site plus all below folders.. then restart IIS... just a thought.

I know this works for IIS 6, not sure on 7...
www.longtailvideo.com/support/forum/Setup-Problems/7481/Why-player-is-not-working-over-server-

1. On the Windows 2003 server, open the Internet Information Services Manager.
2. Expand the Local Computer Server.
3. Right-click the local computer server and select Properties.
4. Select the MIME Types tab.
5. Click New and enter the following information:

   - Associated Extension box: .FLV
   - MIME Type box:flv-application/octet-stream
6. Click OK.
7. Restart the World Wide Web Publishing service.

Good luck!

Comment: I did that already as mentioned on the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `<object>` tag setup to play these to invoke the flash player within the brower.